# locationManager avoid (null) string in a Label

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, stringwithformat

I have some code that find the user location and return it into a Label. In some case, the  subAdministrativeArea is not available or the thoroughfare and I want to modify my string so it doesn't show (null). I tried with some if to check this but there is a problem if the (null) are more than one. Anyone has an idea about this?

Here is my current code that needs to be modified to detect if a placemark object is equal to null:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
        CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
        [location stopUpdatingLocation];

        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

            countryDetected = placemark.ISOcountryCode;
            placeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@ %@", placemark.country, placemark.subAdministrativeArea, placemark.subLocality, placemark.postalCode, placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare];
            userPlace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@ %@", placemark.country, placemark.subAdministrativeArea, placemark.subLocality, placemark.postalCode, placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
}
```

Comment: hi, please ask question elaborately. That should be help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one.. if `placemark.subAdministrativeArea` is `nil` then you can write your own string in if condition otherwise set the value of `placemark.subAdministrativeArea` to the string variable and assign that to `UILable` ...

**UPDATE:**

```
NSMutableString *strLblTexts = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
if (placemark.country != nil) {
        [strLblTexts appendString:placemark.country];
}
if (placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil) {
        if ([strLblTexts isEqualToString:@""]||[strLblTexts isEqual:nil]) {
        [strLblTexts appendString:placemark.subAdministrativeArea];
    }
    else{
        NSString *strtemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",placemark.subAdministrativeArea];

        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>> str temp :%@", strtemp);
        [strLblTexts appendString:strtemp];
    }
}
if (placemark.subLocality != nil) {
        if ([strLblTexts isEqualToString:@""]||[strLblTexts isEqual:nil]) {
        [strLblTexts appendString:placemark.subLocality];
    }
    else{
        NSString *strtemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",placemark.subLocality];

        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>> str temp :%@", strtemp);
        [strLblTexts appendString:strtemp];
    }
}
```

Do same like another 3 field and at last set that value to the `UILable` like bellow...

```
placeLabel.text = strLblTexts;
```

Comment: If I try to use this one and  it is nil, I will have a comma with a empty space between. I would be better to delete the comma if the placemark is nil.

Comment: A much more terse version of this would be: `NSString *subAdministrativeArea = placemark.subAdministrativeArea ? placemark.subAdministrativeArea : @"";`.

Comment: BTW - this is not valid: `if ([placemark.subAdministrativeArea isEqual:nil]) {`. You actually want: `if (placemark.subAdministrativeArea == nil) {` or: `if (!placemark.subAdministrativeArea) {`.

Comment: @rmaddy yes it easy and also complete in only one line... and i not implement it bcoz you already post that type of login in your answer.. :)

Comment: @patapple from which you want to delete comma??

Comment: From the final Label. Now it's like **United States, (null), New York** and if I use your is **United States, , New York**. The best would be **Unites States, New York**

Comment: @patapple oh then its easy just define that code in if and else condition wait i will post...

Comment: @patapple here you get exact output which you define in above comment...try this code :)

Comment: Already tried that. I added if and else but if more than one placemark is null it shows a null in the label.

Comment: oh then here you check every filed and append or merge in another string and then assign to UILable ... wait i will post answer...

Comment: I will try this soon. I will post again here if it'll work :)

Comment: k dude... just write code like otherwith another these 3 fields placemark.postalCode, placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare .. and it will work.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1) Use an `NSMutableString` and only append the non-nil values

2) Update your current solution so each parameter is like:

```
placemark.country ? placemark.country : @"", placemark.subAdministrativeArea ? placemark.subAdministrativeArea : @"", ...
```

Update: I didn't notice the commas in the original question. Due to those being there, your best option is option 1:

```
NSMutableString *label = [NSMutableString string];
if (placemark.country) {
    [label appendString:placemark.country];
}
if (placemark.subAdministrativeArea) {
    if (label.length) {
        [label appendString:@", "];
    }
    [label appendString:placemark.subAdministrativeArea];
}
// and the rest
```

Comment: I am interested in the second option. Could you elaborate what these syntax is?

Comment: The `?:` operator is a standard C operator. In general it is `<condition> ? <true value> : <false value>`.

Comment: @patapple See my update. I didn't notice the commas when I first answered. Since you don't want extra commas due to `nil` values, my first option is the much better choice. It's much more verbose but it gives you the correct results.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand how to use NSMutableString. Why are you doing if (placemark.country) and if(label.length) ?

Comment: I think that appendString is the best way. Need to figure out how to implement it for my whole code :)